# Data window rowscopy

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have 2 data windows, dw_1 and dw_2. I want to copy all the rows from dw_1 to dw_2. My code is

> dw_prnos.RowsCopy(1,dw_prnos.rowcount( ), Primary!, 
>   w_listofinsertedprs.dw_collection,w_listofinsertedprs.dw_collection.rowcount() + 1, Primary!)

My problem is it returns 0. What should I do? Can you please help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both Datawindows have the exact same columns?  Are all the columns the exact same order in the "Column Specifications"?

Comment: Yes, and It is okay now.Thanks for helping